# How to display c++ output message in windows R

Tags: c++, r

My R function is calling a c++ code which will "cout" some lines during its iterations, I can see this lines in windows R called by Command Prompt. But I could not see anything when I directly open R in windows os.

I wonder is there any way to see the c++ output from R under windows but not in command prompt? 
Or if not, can R display something while it’s calling c++ at background?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Printing](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Printing) section of [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html).  You want `Rprintf`.

Comment: Particularly, see the recommendations on not mixing iostreams (from C++) and *printf (from R, or C) as they use two distinct buffering schemes.

Comment: Don't Cross the streams.  It would be bad.

Comment: @PaulHurleyuk: is that a subtle [Ghostbusters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostbusters) reference? ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replay. I have tried to replace "cout" with "printf","Rprintf", but strangely it does not show anything with "Rprintf", but "printf" is working. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: @Joshua Sorry, I couldn't resist

Comment: I have tested it again on a Win visa pc and "Rprintf" seems working, but it is still not working on my Win7 machine, is the os causing the problem?